# Depend on GitHub Dependecies in Android

Tags: android

I have been developing an application and I have came across to add the following dependency in the gradle.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.6'
}
```

I wonder how should I trust the github source code owner? What if source code owner deletes the source code?

Will my project fail if it could not able to find the github path?

Comment: Yep, that's what will happen.

Comment: If they remove the GH repo the aar will still be available. See https://jitpack.io/docs/FAQ/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the library is using jitpack and jitpack uses a mechanism of cache if the user removes the project the `aar` or `jar` will be reachable until the jitpack cache is valid. And at your local gradle also saves a copy of the library.

But your question is more that that, and yes, you should trust in the open source community. If you dont want to trust in `Phil Jay` work.. you can allways fork the project and use the code from your fork or just download the `aar` and import it directly from your project.

If you want to save a copy of the library you can download it directly from here: https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v2.1.6/MPAndroidChart-v2.1.6.aar

Answer (score 2):

No when you first build the grandle, Android Studio look for it in the web, download and compile to use it. If you get it while it's active, you will have it in local drive, and can use it no matter if the source is erased.